# How do I show custom html in the activeadmin form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How do I show custom html in the activeadmin form

I want to show **h1** head in the form with some dynamic values,

How could I get it ?

## Expected

```
exsisting_categories = ""
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.each do |t|
  exsisting_categories += "#{t.name}, "
end
=============> %h1 = exsisting_categories
f.inputs "Exsiting Categories" do
  text_area_tag :exsisting_categories, exsisting_categories, :input_html => { :disabled => true } 
end
```

Comment: check out [activeadmin](http://activeadmin.info/docs/6-show-pages.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
exsisting_categories = ""
ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.each do |t|
  exsisting_categories += "#{t.name}, "
end

h1 exsisting_categories
```