# ActiveAdmin Formtastic nested form custom html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-forms, formtastic

I have such code in ActiveAdmin file

```
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors(*f.object.errors.keys)
    f.inputs do
      f.input :title
      f.has_many  :rights, new_record: false  do |ff|
        ff.input :klass_name
        # ff.insert_tag(Arbre::HTML::Div) { content_tag(:span, "foo") }
        ff.input :rights_per_class, as: :check_boxes, collection: ff.object.rights_list
        ff.actions
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

I need to put custom HTML in the rights part (nested `ff` part). If i place something like `para 'foo'` I get the output at the top of the page, with `ff.para 'foo'` I get an error NoMethod.

The question is only in pushing custom tag in nested form.

Solution from [how to embed raw html in active_admin formtastic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603124/how-to-embed-raw-html-in-active-admin-formtastic) or [How do I show custom html in the activeadmin form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501942/how-do-i-show-custom-html-in-the-activeadmin-form) did not helped

Than you